# Why it is throw an error as "'windows' was deprecated in iOS 15.0: Use UIWindowScene.windows on a relevant window scene instead" in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have project in SwiftUI 2.0 but when I update to SwiftUI 3.0 it is throw an error for

> windows

as a

> windows' was deprecated in iOS 15.0: Use UIWindowScene.windows on a
> relevant window scene instead

any idea?

```
.padding(.top, UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.safeAreaInsets.top)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, the warning message reflects the essence of the problem pretty fully.

Apple really deprecated `UIApplication.shared.windows`, so to fix your warning, instead of `UIApplication.shared.windows.first?` you should use:

```swift
UIApplication
.shared
.connectedScenes
.flatMap { ($0 as? UIWindowScene)?.windows ?? [] }
.first { $0.isKeyWindow }
```

Then, your `.padding` view modifier will look like this:

```swift
.padding(.top, UIApplication
                    .shared
                    .connectedScenes
                    .flatMap { ($0 as? UIWindowScene)?.windows ?? [] }
                    .first { $0.isKeyWindow }?.safeAreaInsets.top)
```

Comment: I see this answer all over stack overflow and it is simply a bad solution for any app that supports more than one scene. And that includes any iPad add that supports multitasking. This code grabs a random scene instead of the scene specific to the view in question.

Answer (score 3):

I saw this code from an apple answer

If you have a view, the easiest way to access the key window of your scene is to call

```
view.window?.windowScene?.keyWindow
```

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/682621

Comment: But `UIView` doesn't have a `windowScene` property. Why not simply do `view.window` ?

Comment: Sorry it's just window, not window scene.  I copied that code, but I fixed it in my project.  Let me fix real quick