# iOS SwiftUI - get the height of top safe area

Tags: ios, swiftui

I tried this:

```
let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.first

print("safeareatop: \(window?.safeAreaInsets.top)")
```

and get:

```
'windows' was deprecated in iOS 15.0: Use UIWindowScene.windows on a relevant window scene instead
```

so I tried:

```
UIWindowScene.windows.first
```

but I get another error, the error messages from xcode are absolutely useless compared to android studios btw

the "solutions" from here:

[Why it is throw an error as "'windows' was deprecated in iOS 15.0: Use UIWindowScene.windows on a relevant window scene instead" in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71538885/why-it-is-throw-an-error-as-windows-was-deprecated-in-ios-15-0-use-uiwindows)

and here:

['windows' was deprecated in iOS 15.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70686543/windows-was-deprecated-in-ios-15-0)

are still giving me this message.

So how to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/60359809/12299030?

Comment: No..............

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `GeometryReader`

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            Text("Something")
                .onAppear {
                    print(proxy.safeAreaInsets)
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With access to window provided in reference (https://stackoverflow.com/a/60359809/12299030) works fine here.

Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5 / iPhone 12

[image: demo]